# How to find where the non serializable type is used in the object map

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to binary serialize an object.

```
try
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    handleNotSerialized(ex);
}
```

When I try to serialize the object with the above code I get the exception:

> {"Type 'MyNonSerilizableType' in Assembly 'MyNonSerilizableAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ef775631550b2f8a' is not marked as
>   serializable."}

I do not know where the 'MyNonSerilizableType' is used.

I can manually inspect each object. However is there any other way to find where it is used so that I can either map it to a serializable type or mark it as [Serializable] ?

The object is a large business object with levels of inheritance and many member types (refactoring it is now not possible).

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Must the serialization be successful? What will you do if it cannot be serialized?

Comment: If you are not restricted by anything, you could do try-catch to have **post-evaluation of your serialization** instead of **pre-evaluation**

Comment: @Ian if it cannot be serialized and if it is necessary I plan to either map it to a serializable type,  or refactor the code to obviate the necessity of the item or mark as nonserialized and restore using OnDeserializedAttribute or something along the lines based on where it is...

Comment: Then I suppose you should rather do "post-evaluation" using `try-catch` block since it will be the simplest solution. Because it seems like pre- or post- evaluation doesn't really matter for your case as long as you know whether it can be serialized or not. =)

Comment: Could you shed some light on "post-evaluation"  (msdn reference/sample code)? I do have a try catch as shown in the updated code..

Comment: I mean, the `try-catch` itself is post-evaluation. Because if you don't use `if-catch`, you will use `if-else` (pre-evaluation) to see an object can be serialized or not.

Comment: I saw your updated code. That is exactly what I meant...

Comment: Nice..:) Thanks. So the problem is that the exception message says which is the type that cannot be serialized (MyNonSerilizableType). But I cant find where the type is used in my object map because the problem type is deep within some other type (from a library)

Comment: Just seeing is someone know a quick workaround than navigating object map using reflection (im taking that path now)

Comment: I see. great.. ;) hope you can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find where the problematic object is located by using reflection to dump a textual version of the object, then searching for "MyNonSerilizableType"

This should get you started:

```
static void Dump(object x)
{
  Dump(x, 0, new HashSet<object>());
}

static void Dump(object x, int indent, HashSet<object> seen)
{
  if (seen.Contains(x)) // stop cycles
    Console.WriteLine("(saw this already)");
  else
  {
    seen.Add(x);
    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
    foreach (var f in x.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags))
    {
      var value = f.GetValue(x);
      var valueTypeStr = value == null ? "null" : value.GetType().Name;
      Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2} = [{3}]", new string(' ', indent), f.FieldType, f.Name, valueTypeStr);
      if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsPrimitive && !(value is string))
        if (value is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
          int index = 0;
          foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<object>)value)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}[{1}]", new string(' ', indent + 2), index++);
            Dump(item, indent + 4, seen);
          }
        }
        else
          Dump(value, indent + 2, seen);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  object someObject = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
  Dump(someObject);
```

Output:

```
System.IntPtr minWorkingSet = [IntPtr]
System.IntPtr maxWorkingSet = [IntPtr]
System.Boolean haveProcessorAffinity = [Boolean]
System.IntPtr processorAffinity = [IntPtr]
System.Boolean havePriorityClass = [Boolean]
System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass priorityClass = [ProcessPriorityClass]
  System.Int32 value__ = [Int32]
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass Normal = [ProcessPriorityClass]
    System.Int32 value__ = [Int32]
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass Normal = [ProcessPriorityClass]
...
```